# Ruby - modifying classes

Tags: ruby, algorithm, class, methods

I wrote simple method which checks if a number is [Armstrong number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number).
But now I want to modify default Number class putting method.
So, I have code:

```
def is_an(number)
    (number.to_s.split(//).map(&:to_i).inject{|x,y|x+y**(number.size-1)}) == number ? true : false
end
p is_an(153)
```

I want to use it as method: `153.is_a?`
So, how I do this?

```
class Number
   def is_an
      ??? How to use object data over here? ???
   end
end
```

Thx a lot for reading.

Comment: Use `self` to replace `number` in the formula.

Comment: or even just drop the variable name altogether, though that is sometimes less readable

Comment: I tried, but it won't work. I found the problem: I had to use Fixnum class, not Number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your original question, but there are a couple of small bugs in your code. You need to pass 0 to the `inject` to use as an initial value. Otherwise, `inject` takes the first value from the list as the initial value. Your current code seems to work for 153 because 1^3 == 1 but it would return false for 370, for example, when it should return true.

Also, the [size method on Fixnums](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-size) doesn't return the number of digits in a number.

Finally, a minor point: the `? true : false` isn't needed because the value of the `... == number` expression is already the required boolean value. So a possible updated method would be:

```
def is_an(number)
    digits = number.to_s.split(//).map(&:to_i)
    digits.inject(0) { |x,y| x+y**digits.size } == number
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating @mikej's answer, plus replacing `number` with `self`:

```
class Fixnum
  def is_an
    digits = self.to_s.split(//).map(&:to_i)
    digits.inject(0) { |x,y| x+y**digits.size } == self
  end
end
```

But I would suggest a name change, to make it more Ruby like. Instead of `#is_an`, which isn't very descriptive, how about `#armstrong?` then you can call:

```
153.armstrong?
```